# Objects which needs to be scrolled down to see are not visible

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm using wxpython to code this simple form. A notebook with a scroll bar and few text controls is what i have used.I can see the widgets which are view-able on screen but the ones which needs to be scrolled down are not visible. In my code below i could see upto "Enter the Logs" and appropriate text control for that fields but the  "review fields are missing along with submit and cancel buttons.

```
import wx
```

import  wx.lib.filebrowsebutton as filebrowse

class Frame ( wx.Frame ):

```
def __init__( self, parent ):
    wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = u"Test", pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 600,300 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

    self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )
    sizer = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

    self.notebook = wx.Notebook( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
    self.login = wx.Panel( self.notebook, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
    self.notebook.AddPage( self.login, u"Login", False )
    self.scroll = wx.ScrolledWindow( self.notebook, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.HSCROLL|wx.VSCROLL )
    vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

    # Sizer for widgets inside tabs
    inside_sizer_h1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    inside_sizer_h2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    inside_sizer_h3 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    inside_sizer_h4 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    inside_sizer_h5 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    inside_sizer_h6 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    inside_sizer_h7 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    inside_sizer_h8 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    inside_sizer_h9 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

    #Test Approve Label
    self.test_app_label = wx.StaticText(self.scroll, -1 , label="Test Approved By :")
    inside_sizer_h1.Add(self.test_app_label, 1,  wx.ALL,5)

    #Test Approve Combo   
    self.tes_app_combo = wx.ComboBox(self.scroll, -1, value='None', choices= ['None', 'approver1', 'approver2', 'approver3', 'approver4'] )
    inside_sizer_h1.Add(self.tes_app_combo, 1, wx.ALL, 5 )


    #Workspace Label
    self.wrksp_label =  wx.StaticText(self.scroll, -1 , label="Workspace :")
    inside_sizer_h2.Add(self.wrksp_label, 1,  wx.ALL,5)

    #Workspace file selector
    self.select_wrksp_dir = filebrowse.DirBrowseButton(self.scroll, -1,labelText = "", toolTip = 'Select tip of your workspace')
    inside_sizer_h2.Add(self.select_wrksp_dir,  1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )

    # Issuelist label
    self.ar_list_label = wx.StaticText(self.scroll, -1 , label="Issue List :")
    inside_sizer_h3.Add(self.ar_list_label, 1,  wx.ALL,5)

    # Issue Text box
    self.ar_list_text =  wx.TextCtrl(self.scroll, -1, value=u"Enter The issue, one per line", style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
    inside_sizer_h3.Add(self.ar_list_text,  1, wx.ALL, 5 )

    # Summary of change Title
    self.change_summary_label = wx.StaticText(self.scroll, -1 , label=u"Summary of change :")
    inside_sizer_h4.Add(self.change_summary_label, 1,  wx.ALL, 5)

    # Summary of change Text Box
    self.change_summary_text =  wx.TextCtrl(self.scroll, -1, value=u"What componet has changed?",style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
    inside_sizer_h4.Add(self.change_summary_text,  1, wx.ALL, 5 )

    # Changed File List Title
    self.change_file_list_label = wx.StaticText(self.scroll, -1 , label=u"Changed File List :")
    inside_sizer_h5.Add(self.change_file_list_label,1,  wx.ALL, 5)

    # Changed File List Box
    self.change_summary_text =  wx.TextCtrl(self.scroll, -1, u' enter list of changed files',style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
    inside_sizer_h5.Add(self.change_summary_text,1,  wx.ALL, 5)

    # GUI Testing done label
    self.testing_done_label = wx.StaticText(self.scroll, -1 , label=u"What tests have you done? :")
    inside_sizer_h6.Add(self.testing_done_label,1,  wx.ALL, 5)

    #FlexGUi Checkbox
    self.gui_check_list = wx.CheckListBox(self.scroll, -1, choices=['GUI Builds Successfully', 'GUI Automation Tests', 'CLI Automation Tests'])
    inside_sizer_h6.Add(self.gui_check_list,1,  wx.ALL, 5)

    # GUI Automation test logs label
    self.gui_auto_log_label = wx.StaticText(self.scroll, -1 , label=u"Enter the logs :")
    inside_sizer_h7.Add(self.gui_auto_log_label,1,  wx.ALL, 5)

    #GUI Automation test box
    self.gui_auto_log = wx.TextCtrl(self.scroll, -1, u'Copy and paste the logs.',style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
    inside_sizer_h7.Add(self.gui_auto_log,1,  wx.ALL, 5)

    # Review URL Text
    self.review_url_label = wx.StaticText(self.scroll, -1 , label=u"Code review URL :")
    inside_sizer_h8.Add(self.review_url_label,1,  wx.ALL, 5)

    #Code Review Textbox
    self.review_url_tbox =  wx.TextCtrl(self.scroll, -1, value=u"Enter the code review URL",style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
    inside_sizer_h8.Add(self.review_url_tbox,1,  wx.ALL, 5)

    #Submit button
    self.sub_button = wx.Button(self.scroll, label = 'Submit')
    inside_sizer_h9.Add(self.sub_button, wx.ALL, 5)

    #Cancel button
    self.canc_button = wx.Button(self.scroll, label = 'Cancel')
    inside_sizer_h9.Add(self.canc_button,1,  wx.ALL, 5)


    vbox.Add(inside_sizer_h1, 0 , wx.TOP|wx.EXPAND, 40 )
    vbox.Add(inside_sizer_h2, 0 , wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )
    vbox.Add(inside_sizer_h3, 0 , wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )
    vbox.Add(inside_sizer_h4, 0 , wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 10)
    vbox.Add(inside_sizer_h5, 0 , wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 10)
    vbox.Add(inside_sizer_h6, 0 , wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 10)
    vbox.Add(inside_sizer_h7, 0 , wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 10)
    vbox.Add(inside_sizer_h8, 0 , wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 10)
    vbox.Add(inside_sizer_h9, 0 , wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 10)

    self.Maximize()
    self.scroll.Size = self.GetSize()
    print self.GetSize()
    self.scroll.SetScrollbars(20,25,45,50)
    self.SetSizer( vbox )
    self.SetSizerAndFit(vbox)
    self.Layout()

    self.notebook.AddPage( self.scroll, u"Delivery", True )

    sizer.Add( self.notebook, 1, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALIGN_RIGHT|wx.ALL, 0 )

    self.SetSizer( sizer )
    self.Layout()

    self.Centre( wx.BOTH )
    self.Show()
```

if **name** == "**main**":
    app = wx.App()
    Frame(None)
    app.MainLoop()

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Try to reduce the code in your question to what is minimally necessary to reproduce the problem.  Also, be sure that it is formatted cleanly.  Right now you have a very "leaky" code block.

Comment: Did you get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code (amended) working on Linux:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import wx
import wx.lib.filebrowsebutton as filebrowse
class Frame ( wx.Frame ):
    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = u"Test", pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 600,300 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.notebook = wx.Notebook( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.login = wx.Panel( self.notebook, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        self.notebook.AddPage( self.login, u"Login", False )
        self.scroll = wx.ScrolledWindow( self.notebook, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.HSCROLL|wx.VSCROLL )
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        # Sizer for widgets inside tabs
        inside_sizer_h1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        inside_sizer_h2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        inside_sizer_h3 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        inside_sizer_h4 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        inside_sizer_h5 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        inside_sizer_h6 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        inside_sizer_h7 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        inside_sizer_h8 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        inside_sizer_h9 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        #Test Approve Label
        self.test_app_label = wx.StaticText(self.scroll, -1 , label="Test Approved By :")
        inside_sizer_h1.Add(self.test_app_label, 1,  wx.ALL,5)

        #Test Approve Combo   
        self.tes_app_combo = wx.ComboBox(self.scroll, -1, value='None', choices= ['None', 'approver1', 'approver2', 'approver3', 'approver4'] )
        inside_sizer_h1.Add(self.tes_app_combo, 1, wx.ALL, 5 )


        #Workspace Label
        self.wrksp_label =  wx.StaticText(self.scroll, -1 , label="Workspace :")
        inside_sizer_h2.Add(self.wrksp_label, 1,  wx.ALL,5)

        #Workspace file selector
        self.select_wrksp_dir = filebrowse.DirBrowseButton(self.scroll, -1,labelText = "", toolTip = 'Select tip of your workspace')
        inside_sizer_h2.Add(self.select_wrksp_dir,  1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )

        # Issuelist label
        self.ar_list_label = wx.StaticText(self.scroll, -1 , label="Issue List :")
        inside_sizer_h3.Add(self.ar_list_label, 1,  wx.ALL,5)

        # Issue Text box
        self.ar_list_text =  wx.TextCtrl(self.scroll, -1, value=u"Enter The issue, one per line", style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        inside_sizer_h3.Add(self.ar_list_text,  1, wx.ALL, 5 )

        # Summary of change Title
        self.change_summary_label = wx.StaticText(self.scroll, -1 , label=u"Summary of change :")
        inside_sizer_h4.Add(self.change_summary_label, 1,  wx.ALL, 5)

        # Summary of change Text Box
        self.change_summary_text =  wx.TextCtrl(self.scroll, -1, value=u"What componet has changed?",style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        inside_sizer_h4.Add(self.change_summary_text,  1, wx.ALL, 5 )

        # Changed File List Title
        self.change_file_list_label = wx.StaticText(self.scroll, -1 , label=u"Changed File List :")
        inside_sizer_h5.Add(self.change_file_list_label,1,  wx.ALL, 5)

        # Changed File List Box
        self.change_summary_text =  wx.TextCtrl(self.scroll, -1, u' enter list of changed files',style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        inside_sizer_h5.Add(self.change_summary_text,1,  wx.ALL, 5)

        # GUI Testing done label
        self.testing_done_label = wx.StaticText(self.scroll, -1 , label=u"What tests have you done? :")
        inside_sizer_h6.Add(self.testing_done_label,1,  wx.ALL, 5)

        #FlexGUi Checkbox
        self.gui_check_list = wx.CheckListBox(self.scroll, -1, choices=['GUI Builds Successfully', 'GUI Automation Tests', 'CLI Automation Tests'])
        inside_sizer_h6.Add(self.gui_check_list,1,  wx.ALL, 5)

        # GUI Automation test logs label
        self.gui_auto_log_label = wx.StaticText(self.scroll, -1 , label=u"Enter the logs :")
        inside_sizer_h7.Add(self.gui_auto_log_label,1,  wx.ALL, 5)

        #GUI Automation test box
        self.gui_auto_log = wx.TextCtrl(self.scroll, -1, u'Copy and paste the logs.',style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        inside_sizer_h7.Add(self.gui_auto_log,1,  wx.ALL, 5)

        # Review URL Text
        self.review_url_label = wx.StaticText(self.scroll, -1 , label=u"Code review URL :")
        inside_sizer_h8.Add(self.review_url_label,1,  wx.ALL, 5)

        #Code Review Textbox
        self.review_url_tbox =  wx.TextCtrl(self.scroll, -1, value=u"Enter the code review URL",style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        inside_sizer_h8.Add(self.review_url_tbox,1,  wx.ALL, 5)

        #Submit button
        self.sub_button = wx.Button(self.scroll, label = 'Submit')
        inside_sizer_h9.Add(self.sub_button,1, wx.ALL, 5)

        #Cancel button
        self.canc_button = wx.Button(self.scroll, label = 'Cancel')
        inside_sizer_h9.Add(self.canc_button,1,  wx.ALL, 5)


        vbox.Add(inside_sizer_h1, 0 , wx.TOP|wx.EXPAND, 40 )
        vbox.Add(inside_sizer_h2, 0 , wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )
        vbox.Add(inside_sizer_h3, 0 , wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )
        vbox.Add(inside_sizer_h4, 0 , wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 10)
        vbox.Add(inside_sizer_h5, 0 , wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 10)
        vbox.Add(inside_sizer_h6, 0 , wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 10)
        vbox.Add(inside_sizer_h7, 0 , wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 10)
        vbox.Add(inside_sizer_h8, 0 , wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 10)
        vbox.Add(inside_sizer_h9, 0 , wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 10)

        self.Maximize()
        self.scroll.Size = self.GetSize()
        print self.GetSize()
        self.scroll.SetScrollbars(20,25,45,50)
        self.SetSizer( vbox )
        self.SetSizerAndFit(vbox)
        self.Layout()

        self.notebook.AddPage( self.scroll, u"Delivery", True )

        sizer.Add( self.notebook, 1, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALIGN_RIGHT|wx.ALL, 0 )

        self.SetSizer( sizer )
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )
        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    Frame(None)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Oh, that's partial good news. Could you try it on for windows if you have wx setup? I'm trying to get it working for windows unfortunately :( . Any idea of what may be causing it not to show all objects on windows?

Comment: No, I don't have windows!

Comment: I just installed and tried in linux and it does work. Thanks for looking into this , i will raise a separate question on why it's not displaying in windows.

Comment: I came across someone using canopy as their IDE on windows that had a issue but when run from the command line it worked. So it might be your IDE if you are using one. Have you tried running from the windows command line?

Answer (score 0):

When adding your items to the sizer, you consistently set the proportion value to 1, with the exception of self.sub_button. It is that which is causing your problem.

```
inside_sizer_h9.Add(self.sub_button, wx.ALL, 5)
```

should read:

```
inside_sizer_h9.Add(self.sub_button,1, wx.ALL, 5)
```

Note also that the posted code `main` is incorrect and should read:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

With those amendments you code should work as you wrote it.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but after i made the changes, still could not view the below objects: self.review_url_label, self.review_url_tbox, self.sub_button, self.canc_button. These are the objects needs scrolling to see and i wonder if this is the case of a faulty scrollbar code. If i remove couple of objects from top and insert the above 4 fields, they are visible. So code for them as such seems to be okay. Objects that will fit in the page without scrolling are visible and ones that needs scrolling are not.

Comment: Glad to hear that you sorted it out enough to be usable. Perhaps you are running on a Non Linux platform, as your code worked a treat for me with that simple tweak.